# How to execute some JavaScript, when printing completes or cancels

Tags: javascript, events

I am executing some script to add some html to the page and add some classes to all elements on the page. Then I am invoking printing by executing the following code:

```
window.print();
```

Now the user will print the page or cancel. On this action I need to remove that html code and remove those classes. So, on which event I can execute the code to remove that html code and remove those classes?

Comment: I doubt that you can get this information using standard JavaScript. However, maybe you can trick around by waiting for a "onfocus" event in "document".

Comment: how about using @media tag for printing specific styling?

Comment: @ SubirKumarSao I am using @media tag for printing specific styling. But I am printing some specific data when use clicks on the print button, without any popup. And I want that when the user will try to print that page, it will print normal page, not this specific data.

Comment: @Debiprasad Maybe I don't fully understand, but couldn't you just hide that data using a `display: none` style inside a `@media print`?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide printing specific styling by using `@media` tag.

```
@media print {
  body { font-size: 10pt }
}
```

You can hide the data with styling that you don't want to print.

See details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: As the wrote on the comment below your comment, I am already using @media tag.

Comment: The problem is that: I want to hide this specific data and display all other, when user try to print using the default print dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.  First I had to add a print library. I used JQuery.PrintPage.  Then I created a second webpage, that was the exact content to print using the print button.  This way, if the user "prints" the page they get the exact page, if they print using my "print" button they get a printer formatted version.

I believe this is all the code I had to add. I added it to my details page `.onReady()`

```
$("#print-link").button(
    {                
        icons: { primary: "ui-icon-print" }
    }
).printPage('@printlink');
```

Preview what I have here for our production site http://www.sc-pa.com/testsearch/parcel/details/0001020003

The best part to this approach is it fails gracefully.  If for some reason javascript is disabled.  The print button will instead open a new window because it is a hyperlink styled by JqueryUI  and the user can use the native browser print functionality.

here is the link (that isn't directly exposed to the user for my pretty print page)
http://www.sc-pa.com/testsearch/parcel/PrettyPrint/0001020003

Comment: Also, not really part of the answer, but I initially tried everything you described and tried to make everything happen with one page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and letting me know about jQuery.PrintPage plugin. I checked how it works and modified my code to load the content to print an iframe and print it.

Answer (score -1):

I reeeeeally think you are approaching this completely wrong and you should really go with media queries like others stated. However just for shits and giggles you could use the following really crappy "solution":

```
(function() {
    document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        window.print();

        var hideContent = function() {
            if (document.hasFocus) {
                var dataElem = document.getElementById('data');
                dataElem.parentNode.removeChild(dataElem);

                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        };

        var interval = setInterval(hideContent, 50); 
    });
}());
```

[Demo adjusted to your question including another ugly hack for when the class is assigned too slowly](http://jsfiddle.net/xnzPV/1/)

Basically it checks whether the window has the focus after the print dialog. But again you should reeeeally not do this.

I have no idea about browser support and it might (and probably should) blow up you pc.

BTW did I already mention media queries are the way to go? Because they are.